# ActiveAdmin - Allow non-logged-in users to view but not edit resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activeadmin

I have a Rails app that I'm using to display database records. Until I have the time/knowledge/resources to create a home-brewed interface for viewing the database records (with pagination and advanced search/sort functionality), I've opted to settle for [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/) to handle these tasks for me.

The database needs to be publicly viewable, and I really don't want to force casual users to create user accounts, so the obvious choice seems to be to disable authentication altogether. However, I only want for admin users (i.e.; me - not unregistered users) to be able to *edit* the database records, preferably through the ActiveAdmin interface.

**Is there an easy way to accomplish this (disable create/edit/delete for unregistered users but allow them for admins)?**

Comment: You need to add custom authentication to the resources I believe. You can write a simple `is_admin?` method and only allow modification if it returns true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveAdmin lets you customise its permissions by providing [a custom `AuthorizationAdapter`](http://activeadmin.info/docs/13-authorization-adapter.html). This has an `authorized?` method that determines whether a user can perform an action. Here's an `AuthorizationAdapter` should allow logged-in admins to do anything, but others can only read data:

```
class AdminOnlyEditAdapter < ActiveAdmin::AuthorizationAdapter
  def authorized?(action, subject = nil)
    :read == action || (user && user.admin?)
  end
end
```

Then [configure ActiveAdmin to use your new class](http://activeadmin.info/docs/13-authorization-adapter.html#setting_up_your_own_authorizationadapter) in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`:

```
config.authorization_adapter = "AdminOnlyEditAdapter"
```

Comment: Wow, that was far easier than I imagined. Works like a charm. Thanks, man!

Comment: Actually, it almost got me there, but it needed one tweak to work right - since I wanted the resources to be visible without logging in or creating an account at all, the `user.admin?` call would return an undefined method error if not logged in. I got around this by changing `user.admin?` to `user.try(:admin?)`